# VR_Do you know any global VR associations?

Tags: virtual, virtual-reality

I'm Carter.

I'd like to know VR developers globally regardless of where they from. They could be literally developing VR games or companies having VR attractions. It's difficult for me to find a list of VR developers.

Please let me know anyone knows any good resources.

Thank you

Comment: Voting to close as this isn't a programming question. This may be appropriate on a discussion site like Reddit

Comment: There is [VR/AR](http://www.thevrara.com/) and lots more devoted to one technology, but really just go to Reddit - the developers are there anyway. In associations you'll usually find their managers...